# Verifying that a string is a valid MIME message

Tags: java, testing, mime

How do I validate that a given string/byte array/InputStream is a valid MIME message without sending it?
For instance, the code below executes without exceptions but the produced MimeMessage is rubbish and will not obviously be delivered anywhere:

```java
byte[] bytes = "somerandomstring".getBytes();
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(new Properties());
MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(session, new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
```

It's certainly not possible to say in advance whether a message will be delivered but some simplistic checks would be great.